# Image animation with speed control

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, animation, controls

We have some problem with our image animation with speed control.

It make use of a timeout to change the image, but we want to change the timeout value with a slider, but for some sort of reason, it doesn't work. Can someone help us out ?

We have a Jfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Kbroeren/fmd4xbew/

Thanks! Kevin

```
var jArray = ["http://www.parijsalacarte.nl/images/mickey-mouse.jpg", "http://www.startpagina.nl/athene/dochters/cliparts-disney/images/donad%20duck-106.jpg", "http://images2.proud2bme.nl/hsfile_203909.jpg"];

var image_count = 0;

function rollover(image_id, millisecs) {
var image = document.getElementById(image_id);
image.src = jArray[image_count];
image_count++;

if (image_count >= jArray.length) {
    image_count = 0;
}
var timeout = setTimeout("rollover('" + image_id + "'," + millisecs + ");", millisecs);
}

rollover("img1", 200);


$(function () {
var value;
var $document = $(document),
    $inputRange = $('input[type="range"]');

// Example functionality to demonstrate a value feedback
function valueOutput(element) {
    var value = element.value,
        output = element.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('output')[0];
    output.innerHTML = value;
}
for (var i = $inputRange.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    valueOutput($inputRange[i]);
};
$document.on('change', 'input[type="range"]', function (e) {
    valueOutput(e.target);
    rollover("img1", 200);
});
// end

$inputRange.rangeslider({
    polyfill: false
});
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You keep creating more and more infinite function calls without stopping them.

After you call your function the first time, it keeps calling itself.
then you call it again with different interval (millisecs) and it will also start call itself....

You can try two different approach. 
1.Use setInterval instead of setTimeout. Use clearInterval to clear the interval before setting it with a new value.

```
/// Call animation() every 200 ms
var timer = setInterval("Animation()",200);


function ChageSpeed(miliseces){

    ///Stop calling Animation()
    clearInterval(timer);

    /// Start calling Animation() every "miliseces" ms
    timer =  setInterval("Animation()",miliseces);
}

function Animation(){
    /// Animation code goes here
}
```

2.Or, Instead, Set your interval as a global variable (not cool) and just change it value when the user want to change the animation speed.

```
var millisecs = 200;

function rollover(image_id) {
    var image = document.getElementById(image_id);
    image.src = jArray[image_count];
    image_count++;

    if (image_count >= jArray.length) {
        image_count = 0;
    }

    var timeout = setTimeout("rollover('" + image_id + "'," + millisecs + ");", millisecs);
}


$document.on('change', 'input[type="range"]', function (e) {
    valueOutput(e.target);
    millisecs = YourNewValue;
});
```